# Error - Objective C - 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <splitViewDetailViewController:'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to use UIImagePickerController to load photos from the photolibrary of the IPad Application. I am using the following line of code :

```
-(IBAction)photolibrarypressed:(id)sender{



  // / Create window
 //self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 NSLog(@"hi");
// Set up the image picker controller and add it to the view

//imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
//[window addSubview:imagePickerController.view];






//UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    //picker.delegate = self;
    //picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.delegate = self;

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
self.popoverController = popover;          
popoverController.delegate = self;
[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
//[picker release];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[window bounds]];
// Set up the image view and add it to the view but make it hidden
 [window addSubview:imageView];
imageView.hidden = YES;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];     

}
```

But however, I am getting the following error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <splitViewDetailViewController:
```

I am unable to understand it.

The app is of SplitView Type and I have used WebView and ImageView simultaneously. So,when I click on the button photolibrary I need to go into the ImageView(I suppose).

Can someone please help me sort out the issue ?? I am pretty new to objective C. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the code for the iPhone and iPad running at the same time. If you're on an iPad, you should remove the line

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

and if you're on an iPhone or iPod you should remove the line

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Alternatively if you want to run your app on both iPad and iPhone, use an if statement to find out which device it's running on:

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    // Display in a popover for the iPad
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

} else {

    // Display modally for the iPhone
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}
```